# Color div with specific value from: value to: value

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

There is API that get time of work about employee day of work, start time and finish time.
in this figure I wanna to show color bar with start and finish time base on value using in my web page using HTML, Css and any another tool
for example if employee work on Sunday from 9AM to 4PM it's show as a figure

[image: 1]

Need any way to make tis practice

Comment: Please read [ask], and since you haven't , take a [tour]. Then [edit] with a [mcve].

Comment: You could use: CSS vars and calc() https://jsfiddle.net/8cgwr4em/